# What does being a "Rookie" involve?

Tags: natural-selection-2

With the recent influx of new players in the game and resulting flood of green text, I'm wondering what being a Rookie involves. Specifically...

**How long does the Rookie period last?**

**Are some servers available or unavailable based on being a Rookie or not?**

**Does being a Rookie change gameplay at all besides the green username and chat messages?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are a "rookie" for your first four hours of gameplay. You can disable rookie mode before that from the options menu, if you like.

Server operators can choose to flag their servers as "rookie friendly", which shows them in green in the server browser.

The only effect of being a rookie is that your name is shown in green. There are no restrictions on what type of server you are allowed to join. It's purely a social thing.

Comment: That being said, you may not be met with a warm welcome if you join a server specifically named "No Rookies".

Comment: This is the correct answer - however from my personal experiences advanced players will still join rookie servers and cream people. Advanced players will also still make fun of new players (especially if they are the commander). At one point a spectator gave away my bases (or lack thereof) to the marines due to the fact I didn't place a hive there. However, I have been in games were people have genuinely helped new players. I recommend finding servers you like and stick with those. With most things YMMV.